# overlaying an image by setting pixel of another image as its location coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I am new in the use of Canvas and Bitmap area of android.

I am developing a map navigator app for my college.  I don't have to use Google Maps.  Instead, I am going to use an image of the targeted location map, for example my college.

Now when a person searches for some place the image should show a marker on that place which should get attach to the image temporarily so that when the map(image) is zoomed or slide up/down the marker should also get zoomed and move with the image.

Is it even POSSIBLE?

What I am looking for is the method for overlaying that marker on the image and attach to it so that it can move with the image when zoomed or slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 Images (with same size or not it's up to u), you want over ride one image to another image, you can do as below:

```
// 2 bitmap images are : Bitmap image1, image2. You know how to get it right?
image1 = image1.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
image2 = image2.copy(config.ARGB_8888, true);

//Get color at the pixel (0,0)
int color = image2.getPixel(0,0);
//Set the color of pixel (0,0) of image2 to same color with pixel (0,0) of image 1
image2.setPixel(0,0,color);
```

Notice that, 2 image must have same config!!

If you want to draw it in your map:

```
//Your Bitmap map must config like above
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(map);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
// Draw yourMakerBitmap from pixel(0,0) of your map
canvas.drawBitmap(yourMakerBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

after you call `canvas.drawBitmap(...)`, your `map` will have `maker` over it. Now you can do what ever you like with new `map` with `maker`!

Comment: In which layout do i get to display this bitmap image?